# How to finish a sub in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I Have a Sub Who opens a new workbook, but this new workbook has its Sub that immediately Activates a user form, and the first Sub never ends, so this is my question How Can I finish the first sub?

first Workbook

```
Private Sub BotonBalanza_Click()
 Workbooks.Open Filename:="C:\Users\proc_221\Desktop\Balanza.xlsm", Password:="genesis1969"
End Sub
```

Second Workbook

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
Application.Visible = False                
Seleccion.Show
End Sub
```

Thank you

Comment: [`ShowModal`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/showmodal-property)?

Comment: If you really want that (do you though?), move the `Workbooks.Open` line into a separate sub and put `Application.OnTime Now, "that_separate_sub"` into `BotonBalanza_Click`.

Comment: Thanks for your support; I need to do it in this way because the first workbook has a master panel for open and use other Workbooks

Comment: Actually `Seleccion.Show vbModeless`

Comment: I Made the changes but displayed an error whit "Can´t execute code in break mode"

Code

   Private Sub BotonBalanza_Click()
   Application.OnTime Now, "Mostrar"
   End Sub

    Sub Mostrar ()
    Workbooks.Open Filename:="C:\Users\proc_221\Desktop\Balanza.xlsm", 
    Password:="genesis1969"
    End Sub

Comment: Yeah, it´s only an example. I don't use it  for anything else

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion would be to deactivate the events when opening the workbook in question

```
Private Sub BotonBalanza_Click()
 Application.EnableEvents=False
 Workbooks.Open Filename:="C:\Users\proc_221\Desktop\Balanza.xlsm", Password:="genesis1969"
 Application.EnableEvents=True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

### In Another Instance of Excel

- This will run your destination open workbook code only if the application instance is visible.
- It will open the destination workbook in another invisible instance and do the job, ensuring the instance gets closed properly and informing of success.

**Destination `ThisWorkbook` Module**

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    If Application.Visible Then
        Application.Visible = False
        Seleccion.Show
    End If
End Sub
```

**Source 'wherever the button is' Sheet Module**

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub BotonBalanza_Click()

    Const ProcName As String = "BotonBalanza"
    
    Dim ErrNum As Long
    
    On Error GoTo ClearError
    
    Dim xlApp As Application: Set xlApp = New Application
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = xlApp.Workbooks.Open( _
        Filename:="C:\Users\proc_221\Desktop\Balanza.xlsm", _
        Password:="genesis1969")
    
    ' do your stuff, e.g.:
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Dim rg As Range: Set rg = ws.Range("A1")
    rg.Value = Now
    rg.EntireColumn.AutoFit
        
SafeExit:
        
    On Error Resume Next
    If ErrNum = 0 Then
        If Not wb Is Nothing Then
            wb.Close SaveChanges:=True
        End If
        xlApp.Quit
        MsgBox "Success", vbInformation
    Else
        If Not wb Is Nothing Then
            wb.Close SaveChanges:=False
        End If
        xlApp.Quit
        MsgBox "Failed.", vbCritical
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    Exit Sub
ClearError:
    ErrNum = Err.Number
    Debug.Print "'" & ProcName & "' Run-time error '" _
        & Err.Number & "':" & vbLf & "    " & Err.Description
    Resume SafeExit
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all; I fixed the error using a delay time on the code.

```
Sub Mostrar()
 Workbooks.Open Filename:="C:\Users\proc_221\Desktop\Balanza.xlsm", Password:="genesis1969"
End Sub

Private Sub BotonBalanza_Click()
Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:03"), "Mostrar"
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
Seleccion.Show 
End Sub
```